# HP Proliant ML150 G6 + Ubuntu 14.04 = very slow GUI

Tags: ubuntu, hp-proliant

I have very slow GUI (in my humble opinion) on my new [HP Proliant ML150 G6](http://www.cnet.com/products/hp-proliant-ml150-g6-xeon-e5504-2-ghz-monitor-none-series/specs/) server with Ubuntu 14.04 installed. The graphic card is the one on the motherboard, and I have a 24 inch screeen.

Is it an expected behavior? Is it the motherboard that is slow, or Wbuntu missing a driver?

Comment: Is this a bare metal installation or inside a virtual machine?  Yes generally server onboard video is a dog and your at a high resolution.  Perhaps it would be faster my connecting remotely with VNC or other methods.

Comment: It is a bare metal installation ... the GUI is really really slow...

Comment: There are two options here: 1) You are using some kind of unoptimes generic VESA driver (which is generally slower than a native driver) or 2) You are expecting way more than is intended for a server, with a graphics card for emergencies and possible for stating installations. The on board graphics on servers are not intended to be used as if you are behind a workstation or behind a desktop,